# How to order data from different table with relation?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Why do all users submit same status?

I have 2 tables, `anggota` and `status`.

I want to take some data from the `anggota` table and use it in `home.php`.

I am using the query below.

When I submit a status, all users output the same status even though in the database table the status is different for each user.

```
// my query:
$query=$dbc->query("select 
    anggota.username, anggota.name, anggota.pp, status.status 
    FROM status, anggota 
    ORDER BY status.id_stat = anggota.id_anggota DESC");`
```

[the status and status table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNGO1.png)

Comment: query in question is missing. perhaps if we can see you update query...

Answer (score 0):

You need a where clause to match the status and anggota tables on the correct ID. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the "order by", you might want to thing about sorting on different columns.

Even better use an inner join:

```
select a.username, a.name, a.pp, s.status 
    FROM status s 
    inner join anggota a on a.{what_ever_the_status_id_column_is} = s.{whatever_the_id_column_is} 
ORDER BY {columns_i_want_to_sort_on} DESC
```